# Android ViewGroup Incorrectly Shifts Up After Navigating Back

Tags: android, padding, toolbar, statusbar

I am trying to figure out why my view appears to shift up after returning to an activity's screen.

Here is the image before navigating away to another fragment.

[image]

Here is the image after navigating back to original screen:

[image]

The xml file of the activity is:

```
<layout
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      />
      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
         .
         .
         .
      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
      .
      .
      .
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Note that I cannot use `fitsSystemWindows=true` because I don't want to create a border at the top of the toolbar, the UI should have a continuous white background from behind the status bar.
Also, there is no keyboard present on the screen to cause this shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` within the Toolbar tag itself i.e

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      />
```

Adding this tag to the root layout created a boundary in the toolbar which I was trying to avoid. Setting `android:windowTranslucentStatus` was not necessary in my case and did not affect the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to you root layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

And set this to your AppTheme

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```